# Getting number of misspelled word in paragraph in php

Tags: php, linux, aspell

I have a textarea in a form and the submitted form will give the result of number of mispelled word in a paragraph.As because i am using linux, i have tried to install the  **pspell for PHP 5**

And i have installed this package

`sudo apt-get install libpspell-dev
sudo apt-get install php5-pspell
sudo apt-get install aspell-en`

but it doesnot work

And this is my code

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$text=$_POST['text'];
$mispell_count = 0;
$words = explode(" ", $text);
$pspell_link = pspell_new("en");
foreach ($words as $texts) {
if (!pspell_check($pspell_link, $texts)) {
    $mispell_count++;
}
} 
$msgSpellCheck = "Misspelled words in text " . $mispell_count;    
?>        
<form name="formdata" id="formdata" action="" method="post">
<textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

any opinion will be fine  and if any other alternative solution

it gives me the fatal error Fatal error:

> Call to undefined function pspell_new()

Comment: ___but it does not work___ is a little vague! Can you be more specific. Does it crash! Do you get error message? In short what is the actualy problem

Comment: Or could it be that I dont see anywhere where you actually put the resulting text `$msgSpellCheck` onto the browser page

Comment: yes it gives me the fatal error **Fatal error: Call to undefined function pspell_new()**

Comment: Did you check a `phpinfo()` to see if the extension is activated in you PHP

Comment: yes it is activated

Comment: Just a guess, but try `pspell_new("en_GB");` or `pspell_new("en_US");`

Comment: No thats not the problem